# Spark submit deploying on cluster mode import numpy as np ImportError: No module named numpy

Tags: numpy, apache-spark, pyspark

This is the error message I am getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "logistic_regression.py", line 29, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

I have installed Anaconda on each node and set PYSPARK_PYTHON to point to anaconda python directory. The master node has the same setting as other worker nodes, what could be the issues?

Comment: Did you set  PYSPARK_PYTHON  on each node?

Comment: Yes I have set it to Anaconda/bin/python27

Comment: Can you confirm this is the path that is seen from the workers?

Comment: How do I do that ??

Comment: For starters sys.executable